# Problem in passing pointer to audio buffer from C# to C++ ATL DLL

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I am having ATL DLL in (VC++) Function as

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP CProject2:: SetAudiotoNDI (LONG size, LONGLONG* Audiobuff, LONG sampling_rate ,LONG 
    no_sample, LONG no_channels, LONG channelId)
{
    NDI_audio_frame.sample_rate = sampling_rate ;
    NDI_audio_frame.no_channels = no_of_channel;
    NDI_audio_frame.no_samples = no_of sample ;
    NDI_audio_frame.p_data = (short*)malloc(no_of sample * no_of_channel* 2);
    memcpy(NDI_audio_frame.p_data, (short*)Audiobuff, size);
    NDIlib_util_send_send_audio_interleaved_16s(pNDI_send, &NDI_audio_frame);
    free(NDI_audio_frame.p_data);  
}
```

CProject2 is the ATL Object and SetAudiotoNDI is Method added to ATL
when i am using this function in C#  using code

```
void ProcessMXFFile()
{
while(true)
{
    myReader.SourceFrameConvertedGetByNumber(ref avProps, -1, -1,out myFrame, "");
                        int size;
                        long pointerToaudioData;
                        int rest = 0;
                        int NoofSample = 0;
                        int c =0;
                        myFrame.MFAVPropsGet(out avPC, out NoofSample); 
     
    avPC.audProps.nBitsPerSample = 16;  
    myframe.MFConvert(ref avPC, out ConvertedFrame, out rest, L"", L"");
    hr = ConvertedFrame.MFAudioGetBytes(out size,  out pointerToaudioData );  
     c = (int)(avPC.audProps.nSamplesPerSec / avPC.vidProps.dblRate);
                        size = c * avPC.audProps.nChannels * sizeof(short);                                
                        int no_channels = avProps.audProps.nChannels;  
    
    SetAudiotoNDI(size,ref pointerToaudioData ,c.avPC.audProps.nSamplesPerSec,no_of_channel,1)

    }
}
```

Code is not working. Noise at NDI Line at studio monitor

And in C++ this code is working fine, both C# and C++ code are running in an infinite loop

```
void ProcessMXFFile()
{
while(true)
{
    hr = cpReader->SourceFrameConvertedGetByNumber(&avProps, -1, -1, &cpFrame, CComBSTR(L""));
                   hr = cpFrame->MFAVPropsGet(&avPC, &Samp);
    avPC.audProps.nBitsPerSample = 16;
    hr = cpFrame->MFConvert(&avPC, &ConvertedFrame, &rest, L"", L"");
    hr = ConvertedFrame->MFAudioGetBytes(&size, &audiobuff);
    LONG c = avPC.audProps.nSamplesPerSec / avPC.vidProps.dblRate;
    size = c*avPC.audProps.nChannels*sizeof(short);
         int no_channels = avProps.audProps.nChannels; 
    
    LONGLONG *ptr = new LONGLONG[size];
    memset(ptr,0,size)
    memcpy(ptr, audiobuff,size);
    SetAudiotoNDI(size,ptr,c.avPC.audProps.nSamplesPerSec,no_of_channel,1)   

  }
}
```

could some one help me out here to get solution.With code snippet will be  high help.
I have added ATL Dll in my references in C#,there is no compile error
But Not working as per logic.I dont know where is the mistake

Thanks

Lucus

Comment: Please edit your question. It seems your descriptions are mixed with your code. Do not indent 4 whilespaces if it's not code.

Comment: Also provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help other to answer the question faster. You current code format is messy. I can't tell which part belongs to C# or C++. It'll be better if code is put in a function like `void func(){ ... something your test}`.

Comment: I feel the problem area is passing stack variable to ATL DLL function.since in c++ passing heap allocated variable to ATL.How to create and copy in heap allocated variable in C#.That variable is Pointer to Long array of size in C++.

Comment: [Marshal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal) is the keyword you may check for C#. It manages unmanaged and managed memory inter-operations.